# How to decode a string in Visual Basic 6

Tags: encoding, vb6, odbc, paradox

I'm trying to read .DB (Paradox 5) file within my `Visual Basic 6`.
Everything's OK except encoding/charset. It shows as `Iieiei 75a` instead of cyrillic string.

This is my ODBC Connection string:

`Driver={Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )};DriverID=538;Fil=Paradox 4.X;DataCodePage=ANSI;BDE=2;CollatingSequence=ASCII;AutoTranslate=No;DBQ=C:\Database;DefaultDir=C:\Database`

Please note that software like `Borland Database Desktop` shows this strings without any problems. Also everything is fine in another PC.

I set following settings via regedit, by it doesn't help:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Xbase] 
"DataCodePage"="ANSI" 
"BDE"=dword:00000002
```

I also tried to use `CharToOem`/`Oem2Char` Win API functions, it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you tell it to use `ANSI` perhaps it uses the current session's codepage?  Maybe plug in the exact codepage your data was encoded with to make it work universally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have solved this by changing following registry values:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Xbase] 
"DataCodePage"="ANSI" 
"BDE"=dword:00000002 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
"1252"="1251.nls"
```

Last setting has solved the issue.